# c++ namespace collision with gtest and boost

Tags: c++, boost, googletest

If I include both *gtest/gtest.h* and *boost/math/distributions/poisson.hpp* I get

```
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:63: error: ‘tuple’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:67: error: ‘make_tuple’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:68: error: ‘tie’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:72: error: ‘tuple_size’ is already declared in this scope
/opt/local/include/boost/tr1/tuple.hpp:73: error: ‘tuple_element’ is already declared in this scope
```

How do I prevent these two library namespaces from colliding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try building with `BOOST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE` defined. It looks like both boost and your `std` libraries are defining `std::tr1::tuple` and I can't see how to disable the `std` version. Looking at the boost header though it appears that `BOOST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE` needs to be defined to tell boost that `std::tr1::tuple` is already defined.

I got similar errors to yours when I tried to compile a file including both those headers and then they disappeared when I defined `BOOST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE`.

Comment: This depends on the compiler version and on the gtest version.
GTest also defines its own tuple unless the compiler is gcc 4+. So in this case boost would use the gtest implementation, which you probably don't want.
But you can use the boost tuple in gtest also by setting GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried switching the order of the includes? It is possible the other header file handles things a little more gracefully.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the order (from gtest/boost to boost/gtest makes a larger mess).

Answer (score 2):

With gtest setting GTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE to 0 in gtest.h helped in my case

Answer (score 1):

To be able to include boost/math/distributions/fisher_f.hpp in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010,
I needed to define `BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_TUPLE` as well as `BOOST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE`.